# I was creating a discord music bot on Repl.it and this error keeps showing

Tags: python, discord, bots

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import asyncio
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncio/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .base_events import *
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncio/base_events.py", line 296
    future = tasks.async(future, loop=self)
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

someone told me to install `asyncio` and so I did it seemed like some of the problems were gone but it still has an error pls help

Answer (score 1):

Tasks don't use `async`, they use `.loop`

Answer (score 0):

Findings:

- **asyncio** is not needed for python3.8. It was merged into python-core, see this: https://pypi.org/project/asyncio/
- Removing asyncio worked for me

Steps:

- Go to your python installation *site-packages* path
- Verify asyncio is actually there: `ls -al | grep asyncio`
- Remove asyncio manually: `rm -rf asyncio`
- Repeat for the **.dist-info** related to asyncio